# How small can I get away with making various logos on Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, logos, widget

I'm designing a web-dashboard. The front page has a 3x3 grid of widgets. In one of the widgets we include the clients' logo. How small should I dare go with the logo?

Comment: Random shot in the dark...100px. Mobile viewports are going to be your smallest. Iphone's 320px portrait view will likely be your smallest standard width. 320-20px for borders/padding/margin = 300px divided by 3 columns = 100px wide each. Of course this is pure opinion based borderline nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, most clients want to make sure their logos are readable.

Logos are tough due to having such a difference in aspect ratios, text size, amount of text. It would not just be a case of how small you can make them, but also whether or not it can be read and works for lots of logo layouts.

Then their is the devices it is being looked at on and whether or not the site is responsive, because that can often help if you are stacking the 3 x 3 columns instead of squashing them smaller. Check Google Analytics to see the most popular resolutions and devices that the users are viewing the site on and judge it from their.

I am sure clients will complain soon enough if you have gone too small.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to provide an objective answer toward this, but it may depend ultimately on the nature of your client.  In general, if the client is a small and relatively unknown company or startup, an argument can be made to keep the logo very small.  Larger companies may have a sizable, intangible value to goodwill and brand recognition, and their logo is part of this - so a larger logo would be best.

Either way, it must be legible.  Your other choice is to simply display the glyph of the logo if the client has one.  In many cases, this can be a simple and effective use of the little real estate on the page.

If the logo includes a proper name, it might be a good idea to display it a little more prominently.  Because, well, who doesn't like to see their name up in lights?

The last part is whether the dashboard is for internal versus external use for the client.  If it's internal, it probably won't impact much if the logo is small.

Whichever way you go, confer your reasoning to the client verbally.